# Why wont e.target work?

Tags: actionscript-3, events, mouse

```
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hoverButton);
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hoverOffButton);

stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hoverButton);
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hoverOffButton);

fast_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, hoverButton);
fast_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hoverOffButton);

function hoverButton(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.nextFrame();
}
function hoverOffButton(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    e.target.prevFrame();
}
```

Hi I would like to understand why this piece of actionscript code will NOT make my play, stop, and fast forward buttons shift to the next and previous frames. Basically, the buttons will jump up slightly when the mouse is hovered over and then back down when the mouse is not hovered. This does work however if I replace 'e.target' with play_btn or fast_btn, etc. As far as I can tell the frames are in the right spots.

Comment: Can you trace what are the objects in e.target and e.currentTarget (I think the trace would give object ids... so trace play_btn, stop_btn and fast_btn too)?

Comment: I traced e.target and my output was [object MovieClip]. Sometimes it would appear multiple times at once when hovered over a button. So what does this mean exactly, that e.targeting is 'targeting' the whole clip?

Answer (score 2):

there is a difference between `event.target` and `event.currentTarget`.

event.target is the object that dispatched the event. In your case a shape or child object of your button.
event.currentTarget is the object on that you attached the listener.

This means, if you are interested in the object that dispatched the mouse event you use e.target. In your case e.currentTarget will result in the way you planed it.

Comment: Another way to handle this is to turn off mouseChildren in the buttons (and this can be done efficiently in the Base Class).

Comment: Thank you to Larusso for giving me the solution. However I still dont understand why e.target would not work. I posted earlier my output for tracing e.target was [Object MovieClip]. What does this mean, that every button dispatched the event at once?

Comment: You have a button movie clip. This Button has a nested movie clip inside it (an icon for example). If you click on that icon, then the dispatcher is the icon movie clip. The event bubbles up through the display list until it reaches the stage or someone prevented the event in an event handler (event.stopPropagation()) You could set mouseChildren to false, but sometimes you need to add the listener to a class you don`t know. Use currentTarget instead. I use currentTarget most of the times. I use target in cases of a menu. There I add the listener to the menu and check which button is clicked